# Magento 2 How to get Admin Customer Edit Page edited Tab details

Tags: magento2, grid, customer-account, customer-grid, custom-admin-grid

Please check the screenshot highlighted part, How can I get which tab  is edited when save the customer
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have found out the file which is triggering the change, from there you can find which tab has been changed, the JS file path is - "vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/form/components/area.js".

In this, there are two functions - initElement() and onChildrenUpdate().

Please check the below screenshots for how I have debugged which one is the element by printing out its label name. You can also use the help of UiRegistry.Please let me know if this was helpful. Thank you.

[image]

This is the image for the output in the console for which the tab has been edited.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Bharath thank you for the answer but i'm looking any way to get which tab is edited from php side in save controller